# Error due to variable size data in Simulink Matlab function block

Tags: variables, size, simulink

I'm working with the Simulink block MATLAB FUNCTION and I'm having problems with the bounds of the variables that I define in there.

This is the part of the code where I’m getting troubles

```
function P_S1_100= fcn(SOC_S1_100,S1_AGENTS_10,time_CAP_100)

         assert(time_CAP_100(1)<100)

         tcharging_a1_1=[0:0.05:time_CAP_100(1)]
         tcharging_a1_2=[time_CAP_100(1):0.05:time_CAP_100(1)*2]
         tcharging_a1=[0:0.05:time_CAP_100(1)]
```

(Where `time_CAP_100` is a vector [1x6])

And this is the error that I'm getting:

```
Computed maximum size of the output of function 'colon' is not bounded.
Static memory allocation requires all sizes to be bounded.
The computed size is [1 x :?].

Function 'Subsystem1/Slow Charge/S1/MATLAB Function5' (#265.262.302), line 8, column   16:
"[time_CAP_100(1):0.05:time_CAP_100(1)*2]"
```

Could anyone give me an idea of how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your variable-size data inputs/outputs, you need to define what the upper bound is. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/declare-variable-size-inputs-and-outputs.html for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, but I still have the same problem. The variable with which I have the problem is not an input/output signal.

Comment: I've bounded all the input/output signals but it didn´t work. I've also tried to state the problematic variable ('tcharging_a1_2') as an output signal and bounded it with the option of the edit data box. However I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Hmmm... do you need to declare your variables with the `coder.varsize` function (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/coder.varsize.html)?

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you, but I've also tried that and it didn't work. I think that the main problem is that 'tcharging_a1_2' has variable size from both lower and uper bounds, since these bounds depend on the value of the first position of the vector 'time_CAP_100'. Moreover, I think 'coder.varsize' is not supported in MATLAB FUNCTION simulink blocks. But, thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: You may be right, I have to admit I am running out of ideas. You may want to ask MathWorks if they have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Only work around I can think of is to manually write a loop with fixed loop bounds to expand `[time_CAP_100(1):0.05:time_CAP_100(1)*2]`. That expression is what is causing the problem. You need to know the bounds of this vector. Then you can write a loop something like

```
% max_size is the maximum length possible for tcharging_a1_2
tcharging_a1_2 = zeros(1,max_size);
tcharging_a1_2(1) = time_CAP_100(1);
for ii=2:max_size
  if tcharging_a1_2(ii) < time_CAP_100(1)*2
    tcharging_a1_2(ii) = tcharging_a1_2(ii) + .05;
  end
end
```